# list files in a silverlight project

Tags: silverlight, list, file, client-side

I'd like to list files in a given folder (which is in another project) in Silverlight. Actually, they are images.

Project A : "/Images/a.png" "/Images/b.png"
Project B : I want to list the files in "Project A/Images/"

I haven't found a way to do it, can you help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection to perform this at runtime. If you set the build action of your images to "embedded resource", you can enumerate them at runtime.

```
// locate the assembly
Assembly thisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

// list all the resources
string[] resNames = thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

foreach (string resName in resNames)
{
  if (resName.ToLower().EndsWith(".png"))
  {
     // do something!
  }
}
```

Note, if the images are in a different project / assembly, you may have to navigate to this assembly before enumerating the resources.