# Getting all the images from a folder in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, c#-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I have added a folder in my silver-light project and added some images in it
now i want a list of all the images form that folder

I know silverlight cannot access the local file, but these files are in my project itself

Can i get the list of all?

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to do this.

I think this link answers your question fully: [list files in a silverlight project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711590/list-files-in-a-silverlight-project)